# Identify this chess set with heavy painted metal pieces

Tags: chess-set, identify-this

Could someone please help me identify this chess set?

I purchased this from a flea market because I love the look of it. It now sits in my game room so the paint won't wear off.

I have looked all over each piece using a magnifying glass and cannot find anything that would resemble a Makers Mark or other identifying marks.  The pieces are fairly heavy and feel like they are made of some type of metal yet a magnet does not stick to them.  I have pictures of each of the pieces so I could enlarge them to see better but even doing that I cannot find anything to help me identify this set.  Each of the pieces has a felt covering on the base.  I thought about removing one to see if there is anything to help me but am afraid of causing unnecessary damage.

Please let me know if I can provide any other information - not that I have much more - or any additional photos I can provide in helping with this question.

[image]

Comment: There are many chess sets with figures that represent the sides in the crusades. I've looked through a couple pages on google and not found anything that exactly matches this set. Is there any information on the chess board itself? Also, have you contacted the person who sold this set at the flea market and asked where they got it from?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree there are many figured sets on the internet, but so far, none like this set. I did ask the seller for information when I bought it and they said they got it after being hired to clean out someone's home.  I have looked all over the board and removed the drawer the pieces set in and can’t find a thing about this! I went to the library to look up Chess sets throughout the years but, I can’t find anything like this set. I want to learn about it so when asked, I will know what I’m talking about. This has now become my personal quest to identify this set!

Comment: Still could be metal though just not iron. No clue as to what the set though.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the colors are a bit different, but that could be age or the nature of being hand painted. Also, you don't say how tall it is. That said, it looks very similar to a Crusaders vs. Saracens set (the link I had here no longer works, but a web search should turn up many similar, if not identical, sets). Based on the information in the now dead link, the set pictured seems to have 5 inch tall kings and is made of "polystone", a material made from crushed stone and polyurethane which is supposed to be durable and provide a heavy feel.

Comment: Hello GreenMatt;  Thank you for responding.  I clicked on the link you sent and that is the EXACT set to a capital T.

Comment: Sorry, I hit 'enter' and ended the reply.  Anyway, it is awesome now that i have something to read.  I am very surprised at the price!  I paid $10 at a Flea Market and it came with the board with storage drawer.  If I didn't like it so much...$$$ Thank you very much for your information regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very nice set for display, but if you are interested in playing and maybe even getting better at it as you indicate, you should also investigate obtaining a standard "Staunton" design set since they are the ones normally used in regular play. That provides for uniformity regardless of who and where you play.  If you're unfamiliar with that design, just google it. Inexpensive sets are available for this purpose ($10 or less). Good luck with your journey.